# Android SQLite query day of month

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, calendar

I'm trying to recover some data from SQLite db that have a date less than today. I got the day from the calendar, it does not give the desired result:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int dayofmonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
String sql = "SELECT SUM(filed1) FROM Table1 WHERE "+Table1.DATE+"<= '%"+dayofmonth+"'";
```

Comment: What is the structure of your table? Is the Table1.Date column in SQL date format?

Comment: yes the format is: "YYYY-MM-DD"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the format of your data is `YYYY-MM-DD` i.e. the date components are ordered from most significant to least significant and zero padded, you can use regular string comparisons here.

First create a string in the same format representing today, e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String today = sdf.format(new Date());
```

then use that string in your SQL, e.g.

```
String sql = ... " WHERE " + Table1.DATE + " < ?";
String[] bindArgs = new String[] { today };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, bindArgs);
```

Comment: Can you help me with this query? thanks
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975593/android-strange-result-from-sqlite)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
String sql =                                                  // Create the text of your SQL statement to be executed.
    "SELECT SUM( number_col ) FROM tbl WHERE date_col <= '"   // Include the name of the date column to be compared. Should be part of your string literal.
    + LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )        // Capture the current date per the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
        .toString()                                           // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 to represent the value of this `LocalDate` value.
    + "' ;"                                                   // A proper SQL statement is terminated with a semicolon. Omitted from the Question’s example code.
;
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that supplanted troublesome legacy classes `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Your comment says you store date-only values in SQLite as text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: YYYY-MM-DD.

For a date-only value in Java, use the `LocalDate` class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard format by simply calling `toString`.

```
String dateText = LocalDate.now( z ).toString() ;
```

Add to your SQL string. Your SQL string was incorrect in that the *name* of the column should be part of the text of the SQL. It should be part of your string literal but you excluded which makes no sense in the context of Java.

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM( number_col ) FROM tbl WHERE date_col <= '" + dateText + "' ;" ;
```

This renders a string such as:

```sql
SELECT SUM( number_col ) FROM tbl WHERE when_col <= '2018-01-23' ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).