# Android strange result from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm populating a ListView with a query that uses a LEFTJOIN. 
I've tried different devices and works fine, but some users have reported to me that they can not see the result you should see the query. 
How is this possible? you should change it?

```
String tab = "SELECT c._id, c.1, c.2, c.date, 
SUM(g.3), SUM(g.4), SUM(g.5), SUM(g.6), g.7 " +
"FROM Table1 c LEFT JOIN Table2 g ON (c.1  =  g.7) GROUP BY c.1";
```

the part of the query that causes problems is:

```
SUM(g.5), SUM(g.6),
```

Comment: Please add some additional details to reproduce the issue. For example, how you schema and data look like.

Comment: I found that the problem is not in the query but in a field in the database. I have now solved. 
Thank you for your help.